# How to test and develop with Google maps API without https?

Tags: javascript, api, https, geolocation, maps

I've searched and searched but I guess I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

I'm working on a web app with Google maps and I am having a lot of difficulties trying to debug and test it. I finally found out why I keep getting errors due to chrome blocking calls made not via HTTPS.  The app works in Firefox, but not in chrome or any other browser I've tried, safari, dolphin, etc. (All works great locally of course)

What should I do? Is my only option to pay for SSL cert for my free hosting account that I'm using to test my app? I'm just a mid-level developer who isn't really ready to pay for hosting just yet... Am I missing something super common that most developers take advantage of in terms of having some solid way of testing? Hopefully, that makes sense!

Comment: try using https://ngrok.com/ it might work out

Comment: This is awesome.. thank you. Seems to be exactly what I needed!

Comment: If it helps i hv posted it as answer. If u want u cn mark it as answer so that it is helpful to others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using https://ngrok.com/ it might work out.

It tunnels your local url to public with https too.

Comment: Thank you! Has been working great after pairing it with npm http-server :)

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome, there is a flag for this at [`chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost`](http://chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost).

Click on **Enable** and **restart Chrome**. From now on invalid certificates on localhost (and just on https over localhost) are accepted.

[image]

Comment: It works fine locally, I want to be able to test it on my mobile devices? As in once it's uploaded to my web host and I visit it on all my devices for testing.